# Policies having Description more than 256 are not flowing to Billing Center

Tags: guidewire

If i do a policy change or cancellation with giving the description more than 256 chars, those policies are not getting updated in Billing center. Not sure what the reason is. The field **description** in PC is a medium text type. I opened the message payload and saw the following error **response " com.guidewire.pl.metadata.datatype2.PLDataTypeException."** Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is thrown from BillingCenter. After binding any transaction in PolicyCenter, the webservice "BillingAPI" will be called in order to transport the BillingInstruction payload from PC to BC. In BillingCenter,  the payload is then parsed and populated to respective billing entities.

So the fields (entity columns) and its datatypes (including specifications) must be in sync.

Please check the billing api code, and find database field to where the "Description" from policycenter is been populated. The datatype(including the size) should be in sync between PC ad BC. If its not in sync that make it in sync to accept the description from PC.

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thank you so much, let me doing it. By any chance do you know the file name of billing api class where I can check? Thanks in advance

Comment: The class name is BillingAPI.gs in BillingCenter. This is a we service class and you can have a debug point on the function (like create submission or cancellation) that you call from PolicyCenter. You can have a debut point in local environment and issue the policy in PolicyCenter. Then you will reach the debug point in billing Center. Ensure your PC and BC is integrated and the message queue “BillingSystem” in PC should be in “started” status.

Comment: Looks like they are trying to map the Description field which is mediumtext to the field called Description in BillingInstruction.etx which is of type shorttext. Will this be the cause of the problem? Also, if i needed to change, is there any way to change the type from shorttext to mediumText?. I found this out only from your valuable inputs. Highly Appreciate it.

Comment: Yes the shorttext is the problem here. Please change the datatype of “Description” field to MediumText. 

Note that, if you change any data type in entity(.eti or .etx) file the you might face a Database upgrade exception during the server start up. In order to avoid the DB exception you have to write a DB before upgrade script before restarting the server. If you are not sure on writing this script, then you can simply drop the BC database and restart the server to update your entity changes. First do datatype change, then stop server if it’s running, then drop DB and restart the server.

Comment: Please mark the answer as correct if it’s solved your issue.

Comment: thank you so much for your valuable inputs. It is working now :)

Comment: Good. Can you please make my above answer as correct.